# Mapping Actions to Rest URI

Tags: java, rest, uri, rpc

I have a resource 'Customer' for which I have REST endpoints defined as,

```
| URI                            | Function                            |
| ------------------------------ | ----------------------------------  |
| /apiv1/customers/              | {GET} Fetch all customers           |
| /apiv1/customers/{customer-id} | {GET} Fetch details of the customer |
| /apiv1/customers/              | {POST} Add a new customer           |
| /apiv1/customers/{customer-id} | {PUT} Update a customer             |
```

Now, I also have to design for some non CRUD operations like

- Fetch top 5 customers by the amount paid
- Fetch the last 3 customers
- etc

How do I design URIs for actions like above?

My take on it has been to introduce a new controller with a separate endpoints for each function like:

- /apiv1/customers/fetch-top-5
- /apiv1/customers/fetch-last-3

I am still not feeling confident about the above approach. Also, what if I want to parameterize these actions like fetch-top-n customers

Answer (score 1):

```
/apiv1/customers/fetch-top-5
/apiv1/customers/fetch-last-3
```

Those are both "fine", subject to the constraint that your implementation can tell that those terminal path segments aren't customer-ids.

> what if I want to parameterize these actions like fetch-top-n customers

The general answer to parameters is to design your identifiers so that they align well with [URI templates](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570).

The most familiar variation is to use key value pairs on the query part, primarily because HTML forms support that spelling convention.  So your identifiers could be

```
/apiv1/customers?fetch-top=5
/apiv1/customers?fetch-last=3
```

But that's not required - you can encode the information into the path instead

```
/apiv1/customers?fetch-top=5
/apiv1/customers/fetch-top=5
/apiv1/customers/fetch-top/5
/apiv1/customers/fetch/top=5
/apiv1/customers/fetch/top/5
```

Those are all "fine".  Use the spelling that works best for the people that you care about.